# How to attach a wireless remote without hardware

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-vista, drivers, remote

A long time ago I had bought an hp all in one system and it came with a remote an receiver to control windows media. The other thing is it had windows vista. I wanted to move this remote and receiver to my older computer containing windows xp 32 bit operating system. When I plugged it in the old computer it did not reconize the device and and required drivers for it. Just as I though. My question is, is there a way I could get the drivers for it to work so I could use this remote on my old xp?

The remote is called an eHome infrared receiver (USBCIR)

Btw I already tried upgrading windows media.

Answer (score 0):

The IR receiver hasn't really changed much since Windows XP Media Center Edition so should work with the correct drivers.

[Troubleshooting the Remote Control and the IR Sensor (Windows XP)](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=ca&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=bph07914)

[Update Rollup 2 for eHome Infrared Receiver for Windows XP Media Center Edition 2005 (KB912024)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7716)

Comment: I have tried te update, and it installed successfully. When i plug the remote reciver in, it say installing device drivrs for bongle+bb ed. I cant find them though and wants me to. I tried creating it a driver in devices under control panel and it gave me errors like code 1,code 28 and code 10.